# How to prevent truncation of 0 in Excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, spreadsheet

I am copying tabular data from a website:  [http://www.infodriveindia.com/TradeResources/STDCode.aspx?STDCode=&City=&State=andaman][1]

But it pastes the numeric value by truncating the leading value. For example 03192 as 3192. But I want it to paste as it with the leading 0 (03192). Please help me to solve this problem.

**Please try to copy and paste that tabular data in the above URL onto your Excel sheet and check.**

Comment: Pasting data into Excel? Shouldn't this be on superuser.com?

Comment: oh sorry, i dont know

Comment: Duplicate of previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the column type to **Text**

- Right Click the column in question.
- Select *Format Cells...*
- Select the *Number* tab
- Select *Text*

EDIT:

OK, try

- Copy data from site
- Right click A1 and choose past
  special.
- Select Text
- Select Column A and use Text to
  Columns
- Select Fixed width and click Next
- Remove unwanted breaks (in my case it
  would be 2, 4 and 5) and click Next
- Change Column 1 type from General to
  Text

That should do it.

Comment: i changed that, still it truncates value. May be the reason is the data i copied is inside a table

Comment: It works when i enter data manually. But when i paste it, it didnt working

Comment: But once copy-pasted that will automatically convert it into number type, he then needs to prep-end the values with "0" somehow.

Comment: -1: Edited but still not a proper answer!

Comment: Thats also not working. Plz try to copy that tabular data onto your excel sheet and check

Comment: I did, that is why I was stating *in my case it would be 2, 4 and 5*. **Remeber to use Paste Special, As Text, and chnage the Column Type from General to Text**

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your version of Excel as to how you get there, but the best thing to do is set a custom number format like

> 00000

for the affected cells.  That way you can retain the data type - it remains a number inside Excel instead of becoming text, also should the results you get start delivering numbers beyond 99999 or decides to truncate them for you then you aren't relying on the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix it with ' (single quote). That's a signal to Excel "treat this value as text".

Comment: it means what??? plz help, im very beginner in excel

Comment: But once copy-pasted that will automatically convert it into number type, he then needs to prep-end the values with "0" somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pasting, import the data (and specify that it is text) - import is found in the data tools.